# Pandas Matplotlib Triple Axis Combo Chart Loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe (df0) from which I get the unique codes and put into df1. I then need to create charts, looping the list from df1 retrieving data df0. This is a dummy version of a larger dataset that will be filtered for certain criteria.

I need to create triple y-axis combo charts for each item in the code column as shown below for Codes A & B:
[image: Chart A]

[image: Chart B]

So far I have been able to use a loop to create bar charts from pivot tables:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import caffeinate

np.random.seed(100)
df0 = pd.DataFrame([])
df0['Date'] = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10',
              '2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10']
df0['Code'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
df0['WindSpeed'] = np.random.randint(1,150,size = (20,1))
df0['Precipitation'] = np.random.randint(1,20,size = (20,1))
df0['Temperature'] = np.random.randint(1,50,size = (20,1))

df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
df1 = df0['Code'].unique()
df1.flatten()
#for item in df1:
#    print(df0['Code'])

for item in df1:
    #pd.pivot_table(data=df0, index='Date', columns='Code', values='Close').plot.bar()
    pd.pivot_table(df0[df0.Code==item], index = 'Date',columns = None).plot.bar(title = item)
plt.show()
```

Ideally I'd like to use this method but I haven't been able to create triple y-axis charts from it.

The closest I've come is the following but two identical charts are produced:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame([])
df0['Date'] = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10',
              '2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10']
df0['Code'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
df0['Windspeed'] = np.random.randint(1,150,size = (20,1))
df0['Precipitation'] = np.random.randint(1,20,size = (20,1))
df0['Temperature'] = np.random.randint(1,50,size = (20,1))

df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
df1 = df0['Code'].unique()
df1.flatten()

####MATPLOTLIB 3 AXIS - BARS:
def chartFunc(item):
    data = df0[df0.Code==item]
    index = df0.Date
    x = index
    # Create figure and axis #1
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    # plot line chart on axis #1
    p1, = ax1.plot(x, df0['Windspeed'])
    #invalid syntax:
    #p1, = ax1.plot(x, df0[(df0.Code ==item) & (df0['Close'])
    ax1.set_ylabel('Windspeed')
    ax1.set_ylim(df0['Windspeed'].min(), df0['Windspeed'].max())
    #ax1.legend(['Open'], loc="upper left")
    ax1.legend(['Windspeed'], loc="upper left")
    ax1.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    ax1.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(14)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), labelsize=14)
    
    
    # set up the 2nd axis
    ax2 = ax1.twinx() 
    # plot bar chart on axis #2
    p2 = ax2.bar(x, df0['Precipitation'], color='orange')
    
    #ax2.grid(False) # turn off grid #2
    ax2.set_ylabel('Precipitation')
    ax2.set_ylim(df0['Precipitation'].min(), df0['Precipitation'].max())
    
    ax2.legend(['Precipitation'], loc="upper center")
    #ax2.yaxis.label.set_color()
    ax2.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(14)
    #ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), labelsize=14)

    # set up the 3rd axis
    ax3 = ax1.twinx()
    # Offset the right spine of ax3.    
    ax3.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.25))
    # Plot line chart on axis #3
    p3, = ax3.plot(x, df0['Temperature'], color='red')
    ax3.grid(False) # turn off grid #3
    ax3.set_ylabel('Temperature')
    ax3.set_ylim(df0['Temperature'].min(), df0['Temperature'].max())
    ax3.legend(['Temperature'], loc="upper right")
    ax3.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())
    ax3.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(14)
    ax3.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), labelsize=14)
    

for item in df1:
    chartFunc(item)
    plt.show()
```

Output is the same two charts.

[image: Chart A]
[image: Chart B]

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "the results are wrong"?

Comment: The charts are both the same. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are filtering by `item` inside the function...

```
data = df0[df0.Code==item]
```

but, plotting `df0` in each case.

```
p1, = ax1.plot(x, df0['Windspeed'])
```

```
p2 = ax2.bar(x, df0['Precipitation'], color='orange')
```

```
p3, = ax3.plot(x, df0['Temperature'], color='red')
```

You need to change these to `data` like so...

First, change `index = df0.Date` to `index = df0[df0.Code==item].Date`

and then, change each plot like below

```
p1, = ax1.plot(x, data['Windspeed'])
```

```
p2 = ax2.bar(x, data['Precipitation'], color='orange')
```

```
p3, = ax3.plot(x, data['Temperature'], color='red')
```

This will give you different plots you are looking for...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you the line: (index = df0[df0.Code==item].Date) also answers a concern I had because not all the dates the large dataframe I'm working from are the same for each code. This makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a sub chart for precipitation like this:

```
def chartFunc(df):
    params = {'hspace': 0.1, 'height_ratios': [3, 1]}
    fig, (ax1, ax3) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(9, 7), sharex=True, gridspec_kw=params)
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    x = df.index
    
    # Windspeed
    c = '#1f77b4'
    ax1.plot(x, df['Windspeed'], color=c)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Windspeed')
    ax1.set_ylim(df['Windspeed'].min(), df['Windspeed'].max())
    ax1.legend(['Windspeed'], loc='upper left')
    ax1.yaxis.label.set_color(c)
    ax1.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(14)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=c, labelsize=14)
    
    # Precipitation
    c = '#ff7f0e'
    p3 = ax3.bar(x, df['Precipitation'], color=c)
    ax3.set_ylabel('Precipitation')
    ax3.set_ylim(df['Precipitation'].min(), df['Precipitation'].max())
    ax3.legend(['Precipitation'], loc='upper left')
    ax3.yaxis.label.set_color(c)
    ax3.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(14)
    ax3.tick_params(axis='y', colors=c, labelsize=14)
    
    # Temperature
    c = '#d62728'
    ax2.plot(x, df['Temperature'], color='red')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature')
    ax2.set_ylim(df['Temperature'].min(), df['Temperature'].max())
    ax2.legend(['Temperature'], loc='upper right')
    ax2.yaxis.label.set_color(c)
    ax2.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(14)
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=c, labelsize=14)

    plt.suptitle('Historic data')
    ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)

df0['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['Date'])
df1 = df0.set_index(['Date', 'Code']).unstack().swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
for code, df in df1.groupby('Code', axis=1):
    chartFunc(df[code])
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]